# Display array from parse.com in tableview (iOS)

Tags: ios, parse-platform

I am tying to display in my table view an array that is on a database on parse.com
I can display the first item in the array, but not the rest.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath object:(PFObject *)object {
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if(cell==nil){
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    }   
    _ListArray = [object objectForKey:@"content"];
    NSLog(@"OBJECT = %@",_ListArray);
    NSString *cellValue = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [_ListArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];

    cell.textLabel.text = cellValue;

    if(refresh <counter)
    {
        NSString *br = @"<br>";
        List = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@%@", List, br, cell.textLabel.text];
        NSLog(@"%@",List);
        refresh ++;
    }       
    cell.accessoryType =UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator;

    return cell;
}
```

If I try to use:

```
-(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return [_ListArray count];
}
```

I get nothing in the table.

edit update:

did remove the self.ListArray and going with _ListArray.

in the h file:

```
NSMutableArray *ListArray;
...
@property (retain, atomic) NSMutableArray *ListArray;
```

and then in m file:

```
@synthesize ListArray = _ListArray;
```

regarding the:

```
self.ListArray = [object objectForKey:@"content"];
```

the object is the PFObject.

i have queryForTable where i get the data from parse.

```
- (PFQuery *)queryForTable {

    PFQuery *query = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"List"];
    [query whereKey:@"user" equalTo:[PFUser currentUser]]; // user
    [query whereKey:@"objectId" equalTo:[theListID objectId]]; // the specific list
    counter =[query countObjects];
    NSLog(@"%d",counter);

    // If Pull To Refresh is enabled, query against the network by default.
    if (self.pullToRefreshEnabled) {
        query.cachePolicy = kPFCachePolicyNetworkOnly;
    }

    // If no objects are loaded in memory, we look to the cache first to fill the table
    // and then subsequently do a query against the network.
    if ([self.objects count] == 0) {
        query.cachePolicy = kPFCachePolicyCacheThenNetwork;
    }

    [query orderByDescending:@"createdAt"];

    return query;

}
```

And to the objectForKey:@"content"];
content is the name of the column in my class on parse
so i need to say what object from the class i want to get, and that is the array column named "content"

The logg, (when the NSLog is active on the array.

```
Inköpslista[7856:12e03] Warning: A long-running Parse operation is being executed on the main thread. 
 Break on warnParseOperationOnMainThread() to debug.
2013-10-21 14:23:31.008 Inköpslista[7856:12e03] 1
2013-10-21 14:23:31.017 Inköpslista[7856:12e03] OBJECT = (
    "Br\U00f6d",
    Anka,
    Boll,
    Sko
)
2013-10-21 14:23:31.017 Inköpslista[7856:12e03] <html><body><br>Bröd
2013-10-21 14:23:31.545 Inköpslista[7856:12e03] OBJECT = (
    "Br\U00f6d",
    Anka,
    Boll,
    Sko
)
```

Comment: Please check what value comes in self.ListArray when you reload data

Comment: How is self.ListArray created?

Comment: In storyboard, are you set the identifier as @"Cell"?

Comment: What is the purpose of `self.ListArray = [object objectForKey:@"content"];` ? If you're using the parse provided table view controller you just need to configure the cell for the passed object...

Comment: Did edit the post for more info. and in the storyboard the identifier is "Cell".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got it to work, did put the array were i get the data from parse, and then only call

```
cell.textLabel.text = [_ListArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
```

and then i can use:

```
-(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return [_ListArray count];
}
```